# beforeFind orderby in AppModel - cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to add an order by to EVERY find in my app. Here's what I'm working with already, but I'm not sure how to inject my order by statement. Little help?

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    if (Configure::read('id') !=0) {
        // Force all finds to only find stuff which is within the current domain id
        $queryData['conditions'][$this->alias . '.domain_id'] = Configure::read('id');
}
    return $queryData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
$queryData['order'] = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3 DESC');
```

Comment: Getting this error:
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created' in order clause is ambiguous

Comment: be more explicit with all of your fields in searches. 'Model.created'

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
    $queryData['order'] = array($this->alias.'.created DESC');
```